# The PDF of Euclidean distance between a point uniformly distributed and several points from Poisson Point Process(PPP)

Tags: probability-distributions

I've met a problem to solve.
In Spherical coordinate system, a point A follows uniform distribution in the space, which is a part that the spherical cone with radius U1 minus the one with radius U2(from the centre of sphere O). Under the O, there is a point O', draw a horizontal platform area with O' as the center and R as the radius. A Poisson point process $\Phi$ with the density of $\lambda$ is generated in the area.
so how to calculate the pdf of the distance between A and the points in the PPP $\Phi$.